# How to find contours of white and black boxes?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently working on an image where I have to find the box outer region. But I failed to find the white and black boxes regions.

input image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrM8p.png

output image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/67B7i.png

Update edit:
if I use HLS instead of HSV I can find 3 more box region but 2 is still missing.
here is new output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbHHl.png

and here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("1.png")
imghsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_blue = np.array([0,50,0])
upper_blue = np.array([255,255,255])
mask_blue = cv2.inRange(imghsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_blue, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
im = np.copy(img)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imwrite("contours_blue.png", im)
```

Answer (score 0):

The mask you're generating with

```
mask_blue = cv2.inRange(imghsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
```

does not include the bottom row at all, so it's impossible to detect these outlines with

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_blue, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

You could try to work with multiple masks / thresholds to account for the different color ranges and merge the detected contours.

Answer (score 0):

Color channel threshold is not the optimal solution in cases when you are dealing with objects of many different colors (that are not known in advance) and with background color that is not necessarily distinctly different from all object colors. Combination of multiple thresholds/conditions could solve the job for this particular image but this same combination can fail for slightly different input, so I think this approach is generally not too good.

I think the problem is very elementary in nature so I would recommend sticking to a simple approach. For example, if you apply Sobel operator on your image, you get result like one below. The intensity of the result is weak on some borders, so I inverted the image colors to make it better visible.

[image]

There are tons of tutorials on Sobel operator on the web so I won't go into detail here. On your input image there is no noise, so the intensity outside and within the boxes is zero. I would therefore suggest masking-out all zero values. If you do contour detection after that, you will end up with two contours per square - one will be on the inner side of the border and one on the outer side of the border. If you only want to extract contours on the outer border, see how contour hirearchy works in the OpenCV documentation. If you want to have contour *exactly* on the border, help yourself with outer contour and erosion.